# How to get the Page Number of a form field in Aspose PDF?

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

How to I retrieve the page number of a Form Field using Aspose PDF?  I'm trying to recreate the PDF form in HTML by placing an image of each page and overlaying each field using the page number, coordinates, and dimensions.

Here's my current code:

```
public static List<PdfFieldDisplayModel> GetFieldPlacements(Stream stream)
    {
        var fields = new List<PdfFieldDisplayModel>();
        var doc = new Document(stream);
        var pdfForm = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form(stream);

        foreach (Field ff in doc.Form)
        {
            var txt = doc.Form[ff.Name] as TextBoxField;
            var f = new PdfFieldDisplayModel();
            f.PageNumber = ??????????????
            f.Name = ff.Name;
            f.PartialName = ff.PartialName;
            f.Value = ff.Value;
            f.Width = txt.Rect.Width;
            f.Height = txt.Rect.Height;
            f.Left = txt.Rect.LLX;
            f.Bottom = txt.Rect.LLY;
            fields.Add(f);
        }
        return fields;
    }
```

Comment: You're aware that a single AcroForm form field may have appearances on multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, I am. I would assume I could get the instance of the field too all with their own unique location: Page number, coordinates, and dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Nayyer and I am developer Evangelist at Aspose. In order to get page index for form field, please try using **PageIndex** property of **Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Forms.Field** instance.

**[C#]**

```
//open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("c:/pdftest/SingleField_output.pdf","password");
//get values from all fields

foreach (Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Forms.Field formField in pdfDocument.Form)
{
    //get field value
    Console.WriteLine("PartialName : {0} ", formField.PartialName);
    Console.WriteLine("Value : {0} ", formField.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Value : {0} ", formField.PageIndex);
}
```

Comment: When was this feature implemented?  I must be using an older version because I don't have the PageIndex property.  I believe I'm using v6.9.

Comment: I am afraid I might not be able to share the exact version in which this property was added. However I recommend you to please try using latest release of Aspose.Pdf for .NET 10.5.0 (http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/entry632625.aspx)  as during my testing, I can see this property in this release version.

Comment: Can the same be done with `TextFragment`s and while you add them in the document? E.g. by using `Document.ProcessParagraphs()` aftre the fragment insertion ? I try to do this, but the `txtFragment.Page.Number` has `Page=null`.

Comment: I see now that the `Document.Pages.Count` gets updated, but I am not sure if it is reliable enough...

Comment: Once you have called the ProcessParagraphs() method, you should get the accurate page count using Document.Pages.Count. However in order to get the page number for particular TextFragment, the document needs to be saved, so that the Fragment actually resides inside inside the document.